# Stack using two queues

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have implemented the Stack using two Queues q1 and q2 respectively as shown below in the code. I would like to get you reviews on whether it's an efficient way of implementing it or now.

**For Pop operation :**
I will keep on removing elements from the Queue q1 and adding it to Queue 2 until only one element remains in Queue q1, then I will be removing that particular element from the Queue q1 to accomplish the Stack Pop operation

**For Push Operation:**

It's simple, I am just checking if Queue q1 is empty then I will start adding the elements in Queue q2 otherwise in queue q1.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class StackUsingQueues {

    Queue<Integer> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<>();

    public  void push(int data){

        if(q1.isEmpty()){
            q2.add(data);
        }
        else{

            q1.add(data);
        }



    }

    public int pop(){
        int x;
        if(q1.isEmpty()){
                    if(q2.isEmpty()){

                        System.out.println("Stack Underflow");
                        System.exit(0);

                    } else {
                            /* I will keep on removing elements from the Queue q1 and adding
                               it to Queue 2 until only one element remains in Queue q1, then 
                               I will be removing that particular element from the Queue q1 to
                                accomplish the Stack Pop operation */ 

                                    while(q1.size()!=1){

                                    x = q1.remove();
                                    q2.add(x);

                                    }
                                 return q1.remove();
                          }}
                        else {

                                while(q2.size()!=1){

                                    x = q2.remove();
                                    q1.add(x);

                                    }
                                    return q2.remove();


                            }

        return 0;

        }



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        StackUsingQueues st = new StackUsingQueues();

        st.push(1);
        st.push(2);





    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work.  In `pop`, if `q1` is empty and `q2` is not, you start removing elements of `q1` anyway.  Even if that didn't cause an exception, it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Also formatting has messed up your indents.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?  Is it an academic exercise?  Because this is a terrible way to implement a stack.

Comment: No academic exercise. I was implementing it on my own for my learning purpose.

Comment: @holroy can you implement stack using one queue?

Comment: With one queue, how will you make sure that LIFO condition is satisfied as you know queue works on FIFO ? Please elaborate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30136/discussion-between-holroy-and-john).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Broken

Your implementation doesn't actually work.
(The question should have been closed, but it already has an answer, so... too late.)

1. The two `st.push` calls will append to `q2`
2. If you call `pop` after that, the algorithm tries to remove elements from `q1` until its size becomes 1, but its size is 0 now, to that will throw a `NoSuchElementException`

=> You cannot pop from this stack, it's broken

#### Missing methods

A sorely missing method is `isEmpty` (or `empty`).
Without such method,
there's no really easy way to explore the elements of a stack.
Basically keep popping until the program crashes? Not very ergonomic.

#### Avoid `System.exit`

`System.exit` doesn't belong in the middle of an algorithm.
In fact it's best to avoid it altogether.
It's extremely rare when using this is the right way to go in Java.

#### Popping an empty stack

Java has an exception dedicated to popping an empty stack,
called [`EmptyStackException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html).
How could you know that?
When reinventing the wheel,
it's good to look at the SDK ([`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) in particular, in this case),
to learn from what exists.

#### Implementation

Suggested implementation, using your algorithm idea:

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class StackUsingQueues<T> {

    private Queue<T> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
    private Queue<T> q2 = new LinkedList<>();

    public void push(T data) {
        q1.add(data);
    }

    public T pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        while (q1.size() > 1) {
            q2.add(q1.poll());
        }
        T top = q1.poll();
        Queue<T> temp = q1;
        q1 = q2;
        q2 = temp;
        return top;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return q1.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Note that this algorithm is fast for pushes but slow for pops.
The opposite is also possible: fast for pops but slow for pushes.
For that alternative approach, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/688299/641955) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My bad.  I'll try to remember to partially answer a broken question in a comment instead.  Also, +1, better review.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not efficient, if indeed it can be made to work.  The `pop` operation has a loop that can iterate over N - 1 elements of an N deep stack.  Typically both push and pop are expected to be constant time, as they are in the standard `Stack` implementation.  An additional disadvantage to this implementation is that it can only hold `int`.

Comment: So I can use `<T>` instead of `<Integer>`, right?

Comment: For the record, I don't think that push and pop can be efficient at the same time when using queues to implement. You have to pick one of them. I think the question is from a programming exercise, not a serious approach to implementing a stack.

Comment: @john your class would have a type parameter itself which it would use as a type argument to the queue; as of now, changing the queues to `<T>` will be an error since `T` is undefined.

Comment: @janos right, just wanted to make sure someone answered OP's "is this an efficient implementation" before the question got closed - which apparently ironically prevented that from happening anyway =/.

Comment: It didn't prevent, questions with answers can be closed. I answered anyway because I was more than halfway through my review...